# Why does my script not working in internet explorer but working fine in chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Why do I get following **errors** to execute script in **internet explorer** :

```
1. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {stacktrace=, error=invalid session id, message=session null does not exist}

2. Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

Comment: Share your script as well, not just the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a mismatch between the browser version and Selenium.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023244

Also, IE [requires additional configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023244).